# Loader snaps for msi

Tags: windows, debugging, dll, windows-installer

Is it possible to turn on "loader snaps" for an .msi package and log the dlls that are loaded during installation? I know how to do it for an .exe but not for a .msi.

Comment: a msi is ran by msiexec.exe so I'd say it's the same story

Comment: CharlesB is right, an MSI is handled by the OS process "msiexec.exe", so you need to watch the loading operations performed by this executable when running the install.